# What does the Gowalla Navigation Bar consist of?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I just saw the navigationbar of the Gowalla iPhone Application, and I would like to know what it consists of, and how I could achieve something similar.

Here is a image showing what it looks like:

http://edge.virbcdn.com/_f/cdn_images/resize_1280x640/0c/PageImage-489404-1986468-photo21PNG.png

Answer (score 1):

Navigation bar + something below that is just a segmentedControl (in essence) but looks like its  connected to the navbar (but not really..).

Comment: how could I achieve that effect?

Comment: I dont really know your graphic skills, but start from using the same colors maybe ?

Comment: I mean so that you have a slice of the navbar covering the segment control?

Comment: it doesnt actually cover the control. its just a background image